# Wordpress image gallery shows blank photos

Tags: wordpress, image, gallery

I have created Wordpress site (theme Ellie) and there are 2 language versions. The image galleries on English pages looks correct. However, on the Finnish page the image gallery shows ghost pictures = pics that are not really there and they are blank. I tried to use the same galleries but it always shows like this on the Finnish site:

[Galleries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y502P.png)

I have used Modula to create the galleries.

https://senjacosmetics.com/press/?lang=fi

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what plugin for translation you're using, but make sure your images/media are not set for translation.

Comment: Can you give an example for a problematic image? What is the src in English and what is the src in Finnish version?

Comment: I use WPML for translation. Any hint where I can find the setting for image translation?

Comment: I found the WPML settings and changed those so that the images are not translatable. However, no change in the galleries. Should I re-post them or something?

Comment: I cannot get the HTML tags as once you try to open the ghost pic, it's just loading. All the pics in the galleries (FI) have the problem, I suppose.